# Excel Shape row and column for buttons of same name

Tags: excel, vba

I have various shapes on my excel 07 worksheet which are identical (same name, same function linked to it).

I need to know which of these is pressed (TopLeft Row/Column). Application.Caller correctly identifies the name, but since there are multiple instances of it I am then unable to identify which one it pressed.

Since I am copying the shapes numerous times would prefer for them to be all called the same.

Comment: If you call them all the same then you can't tell them apart using Application.Caller

Comment: Indeed, hence the question. Surely there must be another way.

Comment: Write a macro to rename all your shapes uniquely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on comments by Tim Williams above, renaming all shapes uniquely can be done by

```
  Dim sh As Shape
  For Each sh In ActiveSheet.Shapes
       sh.Name = "Button_" & sh.ID
  Next sh
```

and then Application.Caller works fine. This solution may not look good for some applications, but it works.